# How to install Allegro 5 on Mac oSX Lion with XCode

Tags: xcode4, osx-lion, allegro5

I am new to mac development and was wondering how I can install Allegro 5 on my Mac. I want to use allegro with Xcode, and I am running Lion. How do I install allegro?

Comment: Have you read the readme files that come with the source? What is the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 1):

This can found here: http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=OSX,_Xcode_4,_Framework

If you are using OS X Lion (10.7.x) and Xcode 4.3 you will run into an issue that is not explained in the wiki. When I would attempt to create a new project and include all the frameworks as instructed and after several hours of truing to find an answer I finally stumbled across my issue.

What you may see is an error similar to: 

     `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from: ......`


This is because for whatever reason AllegroMain-5.0.framework was not added to Summary->Linked Frameworks and Libraries. once you add this its should work!

Answer (score 0):

- Install homebrew in [Link](https://brew.sh)

Use the Brew by following these steps:

brew install cmake

brew install zlib
brew install freetype
brew install jpeg
brew install libogg
brew install physfs
brew install libpng
brew install flac
brew install ffmpeg

brew install allegro5

Works for me